# How to save multiple parsed files individually

Tags: java, parsing, pdf

I have some code that loops through all the pdfs in a folder and parses them to text. 
My issue now is how to save each of the new text files as individual documents.

Here is my parser code:

```
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
PDDocument pdDoc = null;
COSDocument cosDoc = null;
String parsedText=""; // append the text to this every time
File folder = new File("/yourFolder"); // put all the pdf files in a folder
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); // get all the files as an array

for (File file : listOfFiles) { // cycle through this array 
    if (file.isFile()) { // for every file
         try { //do the same 
             PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
             parser.parse();
             cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
             pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
             pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
             pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
             pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages()); // if always till the last page
             parsedText += pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc) +  System.lineSeparator(); // append the text to the String
```

I'm not sure how to save the new text files individually from this. 
I was going to write the parsed files to a text file inside the for loop using this

```
try (FileWriter newfile = new FileWriter("C:/Placeholder.txt")) {
newfile.write(parsedText); 
newfile.flush();
}
```

But this will save all files in one text file instead of saving them as individual files.

I feel like the answer is simple but I'm stuck.

Any help?

Comment: replace `parsedText += ` with `parsedText = `

Comment: ...and choose individual file names for the text export...